# Develop ASP.NET Core 2+ Application with Windows Authentication in VS Code without Admin Privilege on Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, windows-authentication, iis-express, kestrel

I am developing using VS Code on Windows.
The application is ASP.NET Core 2 or 3.
The enterprise domain is setup to use Windows Authentication.
Kestrel requires admin privilege for `setspn`.
I cannot figure out a way to run IIS Express from VS Code or command line.
And even if I did, I am wondering how I will be able to debug using OmniSharp?

What is your VS Code workflow to run and debug your ASP.NET Core applications against Windows Authentication?

I know the MS Visual Studio might be easier but it is not an option for me.
Please help.

### Update

### Unable to use Kesterel:

According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel), Kesterel only uses Negotiate for Windows Authentication and this requires `setspn` with admin privilege because it uses User Mode. Is there a way to go around that?

### Cannot figure out how to use IIS Express:

What is the `-clr` version option of ASP.NET Core 2/3? The default value is v4 which seems to be for ASP.NET (i.e. Framework).

Also, even when I specify the `-path` option, I notice that IIS Express gives the info that it copied and used the default configuration file. By default, Windows Authentication is disabled there. Do I need to edit or create my own configuration file? What options do I need to change or make sure that I have?

### Wondering how to debug in VS Code:

I know how to attach to Chrome and Node. Would you please direct me to a documentation on how to attach to IIS Express?

Comment: 1) "Kestrel requires admin privilege for setspn", not true. NTLM does not require SPN and is enough for local Windows authentication testing. 2) "I cannot figure out a way to run IIS Express from VS Code or command line"? The article is rather clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line Once the process is running you can attach to it in VSCode. You'd better edit the question to be more specific.

Comment: @LexLi Hi. Thank you for passing by. I have updated my question as recommended. Would you please try to address my specific questions and challenges?